# useState is not updating the State

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I want to set some token value when user sign In and for that I've created a state by useState hook. But when i call the setter function the value is not updating.
App.js

```
const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(false)

    const authContext = useMemo(() => ({
        signIn: () => {
            setUserToken(true)
            console.log('sign in called')
            console.log('userToken: ',userToken)
            setIsLoading(false)
         },
        signOut: () => {
            setUserToken(false)
            console.log('sign out called')
            console.log('userToken: ',userToken)

            setIsLoading(false)
        },
        signUp: () => {
            setUserToken(true)
            console.log('sign up called')
            setIsLoading(false)
        },
    }))
```

Login.js

```
const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext)

const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (isValidEmail && isValidPassword) {
        signIn()
    } 
}

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signInCont} onPress={handleSubmit}>
    <Text style={styles.signInTxt}>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

everytime userToken is 'false'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I like to think about the useState modifier function is that it is asynch; i.e., the update is not immediate.

This is why you would probably want to look at a `useEffect` hook to handle the side effect of the state change; for instance:

```
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(false)

    const authContext = useMemo(() => ({
        signIn: () => {
            setUserToken(true)
            console.log('sign in called')
            setIsLoading(false)
         },
        signOut: () => {
            setUserToken(false)
            console.log('sign out called')

            setIsLoading(false)
        },
        signUp: () => {
            setUserToken(true)
            console.log('sign up called')
            setIsLoading(false)
        },
    }))

    useEffect(() => console.log('userToken: ', userToken), [userToken])
```

The above (if I've typed it right) will now print the state update, as a Side Effect of the state change; so for instance, if you are setting the `userToken`, then the time to fetch some data (say the user profile) would be in the side effect of the state change.

Please see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html